# How to remove 'allow unauthenticated' flag of existing GCP cloud function using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I've been trying to look for ways to remove the invocation using Terraform but I can't seem to find it. I can't remove an existing cloud function as it is live in production. I know the manual way of removing the 'allUsers' role in a cloud function to remove the 'allow unauthenticated' in GCP console but this won't do as it will take a lot of time so it needs to be automated. Also, I tried it using cloud shell using the command below but there are almost 100 functions per environment so it needs to be automated. Hoping someone has an idea. Thanks!

```
glcloud alpha functions remove-iam-policy-binding FunctionName --region=us-central1 --member=allUsers --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
```

Comment: what's your current terraform? How the IAM policy are set on Cloud Functions?

Comment: we don't have IAM policy set via Terraform so I will be the one who will create it in fixing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use that [Terraform definition](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/wiardvanrij/ipv4google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_cloud_function_iam). Pick the first one: [google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/wiardvanrij/ipv4google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_cloud_function_iam#google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_policy). It's authoritative and will override any existing policies. Be sure to allow the valid account on that Cloud Functions, and be sure that the `allUsers` is not granted as cloudfunctions.invoker.

Comment: thanks! I'm trying that but I'm just having a hard time with the cloud function argument (cloud_function = google_cloudfunctions_function.function.name), is it possible to modify an existing cloud function? because we don't have a google_cloudfunctions_function resource in our Terraform repo.

Comment: You need to define your Cloud Functions in your Terraform script and to import the resource in the tf.state. It's not so easy to use terraform on an existing project, it's easiest on a new project, from scratch

Comment: thanks for your inputs. is there any way to automate the removal of the 'allow unauthenticated' flag in the cloud functions?

Comment: Script and loop. I don't see any other solutions